# Determine IP of WiFi Hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, ip-address, wifi-configuration

On Mac when I set up a wifi hotspot, the ip is easy to determine. But I set up my Windows 8 laptop as a wifi hotspot and am unable to figure out its IP. I need the Ip in order to set up socketServers.
I tried IPCONFIG /ALL in cmd but I get a list of Physical Addresses for all adapters.

Answer (score 1):

Try just `ipconfig`, without `/all`. It should come up with something like this:

> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%xx
>
> **IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100**
>
> ...

Look for all occurrences of `IPv4 Address`. Choose the one you need based on the entry's name (like `Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection` in the example above).